# Probability of a pair of vertices being selected in a random subset of k vertices

Tags: probability

Let $G$ be a graph of $n$ vertices.  I select $k$ vertices uniformly at random.  What is the probability that a specific pair of vertices are in the subset?

Comment: There are ${n\choose{k}}$ ways to choose the vertices, of which ${{n-2}\choose{k-2}}$ contain a particular pair, so the probability is $\frac{k(k-1)}{n(n-1)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{n}{k}$ equally likely ways to choose $k$ vertices.

There are $\binom{n-2}{k-2}$ ways to choose $k$ vertices that include a specific $2$, say Alicia and Beti, since we have to choose $k-2$ vertices from $n-2$ to accompany the two friends.

Divide. The resulting expression $\dfrac{\binom{n-2}{k-2}}{\binom{n}{k}}$ can be considerably simplified.

**Another way:** The probability that the vertex Alicia is chosen is $\frac{k}{n}$. **Given** that Alicia is chosen, the probability that vertex Beti is chosen is $\frac{k-1}{n-1}$. Thus the probability they are both chosen is $\frac{k}{n}\cdot\frac{k-1}{n-1}$.